# App Inventor - Defining local variables using "length of list" equal to tinyDB GetTags

Tags: list, global-variables, local-variables, app-inventor

I am currently trying to design a booking system for my app, and i want to make it so that i should be able to store under a tag a certain list however i am having problems trying to make this tag be automatically generated as in the block of code it should automatically generate the tag to store the booking details ,however when i run the code it app it doesn't make more than 1 tag and so the tag remains the same even if the booking button is clicked multiple times and so it overwrites the previous data.

[Link to code Booking page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUFfc.png)

I want to make it so a new tag for the db is produced each time the button is pressed.

[Link to code Viewing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/049se.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method maybe help you to solve your problem. I'm using TinyDB. I just show how we can add new item in the list of the same tag.

[image]

Next, what do you mean by "so a new tag for the db is produced each time the button is pressed"? Do you want random tag?

Comment: No problem, it's just to keep the answer useful if the link becomes dead :)